# getElementById cannot grab control on the form

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have the following search form:

```
<form method="get" action="SearchResults.asp" id="frmSearch" name="frmSearch">
                <input id="q" name="q" type="text" size="50" />

                <input type="submit" value="Search" id="button1" name="button1" />

            </form>
```

I add Javascript to the form submit event using the following:

```
window.onload = function(){
var frm = document.getElementById("frmSearch");
        if (window.addEventListener){


            frm.addEventListener('submit',function() {validate(frm);} ,false);

        }else if (window.attachEvent){

            frm.attachEvent('onsubmit', function() {validate(frm);} );
        }
    }
```

The validate function is as follows:

```
function validate(frm) {
alert(frm.id);
        var inputs = frm.getElementsByTagName("input");
        alert(inputs[0].id);
            alert(frm.getElementById("q"));
            if (frm.getElementById("q").value=='') {
                alert("Please enter your search terms.");
                frm.getElementById("q").focus();
                return false;
            }

            frm.getElementById("button1").disabled = true;

            return true;    
        }
```

The validate function runs but apparently errors out as Javascript ignores the line

```
frm.getElementById("q")
```

because `alert(frm.id);` returns form id `"frmSearch"`, `alert(inputs[0].id)` returns `"q"` which is the id of the textbox, but `alert(frm.getElementById("q"))` does not display anything at all, not even empty alert box.

Can anyone help me diagnose the issue?

Comment: `getElementById` is a method of `document` only, elements don't have it.

Comment: Don't use alert for debugging. Open the browser's Javascript console, see if there are any errors, and use `console.log()` to print out elements.

Comment: you could use `frm.querySelector('#q')`

Comment: You should also cache `getElementById("q")` instead of repeatedly searching for the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` is a method of document, not every HTML element. You'd need to call `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: What would be the best way to access controls within a div?

Comment: You could use frm.querySelector('#q')

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_queryselector.asp